# Max value of VARCHAR field oracle

Tags: oracle, max, varchar2

I have a field that I would like to get the max value of but it is a varchar2(6) field, all numerals. I am unable to change the type of field

The field is a date listed like this 201307  for July 2013.  Just using MAX does not work.

Using oracle.

Comment: What's not working when using `max()`?

Comment: If the data is supposed to represent a Month, what do you mean by "max value"? It would be reasonable to assume that by "max" you actually mean "latest", so as Matt says, `MAX()` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(date) "MostRecent" FROM tablename;
```

Should work. YYYYMM is going to sort as newest first in a MAX aggregate or analytic function in Oracle.